# Import .sql file to mysql

Tags: mysql

Добрый времени суток!

Уточните, пожалуйста, как мне импортировать через командную строку .sql файл в mysql
**НО** в данном SQL файле хранятся только SQL запрос на INSERT.

Примерно такого вида:

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (1,2,3,4);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (2,2,3,4);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (3,2,3,4);
```

P.S. source file.sql, db < file.sql не подходят.

Answer (score 1):

mysql -uuser -ppass db_name < file.sql - не подходит?

Comment: 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysql -uroot -p8658000 kot < C:/1.sql' at line 1
Дык вот тютю...
Причем, если загружать файл через navicat (к примеру), то всей окей грузится - но падла долго(( Ибо почти 2 миллиона строк.

Comment: >> C:/1.sql

Так нужно сначала файл залить на сервер, а потом указать его правильный путь.

Comment: Я пытаюсь загрузить на локалку, через console встроенный в navicat.
Пример команд:
mysql> use kot;
Database changed
mysql> source C:\1.sql;
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'source C:\1.sql' at line 1
mysql> SELECT * FROM authentication LIMIT 0, 1;
| id | key                              | create              | remove |
+----+----------------------------------+---------------------+--------+
|  1 | c67a7ac736e13906379cae4e86449b24 | 2015-01-21 22:20:48 | NULL   |
1 row in set
mysql>

Answer (score 0):

Давайте определимся, где стоит мускул: локально (на вашем компе) или в сети (на удаленном серваке)? Если локально и под виндой, то Ваша команда на раскрытие дампа верна, если на удаленке, то надо действительно залить сначала файл на сервер.

Ответ сервера прост: "синтасическая ошибка" - нам [сюда](http://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/15.html).

И проверьте версии серверов: тот, с кого делался дамп и Вашего.
И вообще проверьте, а в вашей базе есть таблицы с нужными именами, в которые Вы пишете данные или это просто пустая база? В противном случае придется CREAT TABLE...
И гуглите больше...